# Reinstallation troubles

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uninstall

I currently have ubuntu 14.04 and mainly use windows 7. I don't know what partitioning is and I don't know how ubuntu was originally installed on my computer. All I know is that the 14.04 is very buggy and won't even boot properly.

So I just downloaded another ubuntu 14.04 iso file and burned it to a dvd. Now I want to uninstall my current ubuntu and install it again using the cd.

The problem is, I don't know how. I read a thread that said to download MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition to get rid of ubuntu but it didn't say anything else.

When I run the wizard I get this image and I'm too scared to change anything.

[image]

So here is my main problem in case I wasn't clear.

I want to install ubuntu 14.04 alongside my windows 7.
To do this, I need to uninstall my current buggy ubuntu then install ubuntu again from a cd. How do I uninstall my current buggy ubuntu?

Comment: @muru I found it. I was in my C: drive in a folder called *ubuntu*. Is this normal.

Comment: Ah, you installed Ubuntu using [Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) from within Windows? To remove Ubuntu, go to the Add/Remove Programs section in the Control Panel and uninstall Ubuntu. Then follow the question that Luis has linked to.

Comment: @muru Ah thank you very much. I uninstalled it. Well what do you think I should do. Should I install ubuntu 14.04 using wubi? Or should I just use the DVD that I just burnt the 14.04 .iso file onto? Is there a difference? (I want to keep windows 7 though)

Comment: Well, considering that you already had a buggy experience with Wubi, why not try a normal install this time? You can use the DVD, and remember to choose "Install alongside Windows". It should leave Windows 7 untouched. The link posted by @LuísdeSousa has the steps.

Comment: @muru Thank you again for the help. Should I delete this question now? Apparently it's a duplicate.